# How to Integerate $\frac{x}{x^2-4x+8}$?

Tags: calculus

I want to know how to integrate this ?
$$\frac{x}{x^2-4x+8}$$

Thanks all

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik By finding a primitive?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe That was a dumb question... sorry :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik As being mortals we are bound to be in error as long as we live. So there's no reason to be sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can rewrite this as $$\frac{x}{x^2-4x+4+4}=\frac{x}{(x-2)^2+4}=\frac{x}{(x-2)^2+2^2}.$$ Try the substitution $$x-2=2\tan\theta.$$ This means that $x=2+2\tan\theta$ and $\frac{dx}{d\theta}=2\sec^2\theta,$ and we also have $$(x-2)^2+2^2=2^2(\tan^2\theta+1)=2^2\sec^2\theta.$$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: thank you can I say x=2u-2?

Comment: You sure can. That gives you $\frac{dx}{du}=2$ and $(x-2)^2+2^2=4u^2+4,$ so if you happen to know how to integrate (constant multiples of) $$\frac{u-1}{u^2+1},$$ then you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Factor the denominator into $(x-2)^2+4$, and then transform variables $y=x-2$. The result should be familiar, (Hint 2: it involves $arctan$).

Answer (score 0):

You might try $u$ substitution with $u=x^2-4x+8$  What is $du?$

Comment: Are you sure this is going to work more nicely than direct Partial Fractions? ;)

Comment: @AhaanRungta:  There are several techniques that work here.  This was the first I saw, because the $xdx$ looked like $du$ to me.  I'm not sure it is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

write it inthe form$$x=A(\frac{d}{dx}(x^2-4x+8))+B$$FIND $A$,$B$.then substitute in the integrand.